# Solving and Plotting equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have this equation : 
$$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x^2-2x} - \frac{x+1}{x} = \frac{x-1}{x+2}$$

I want to graph this equation and also solve it using Mathematica . And I really confused about usage of this application. I will happy if anybody write the code for solving and plotting it .

Thank You!

Comment: Normally people graph functions, not equations. What is it you really intend to do?

Comment: Do you have a copy of Mathematica?  If so, look-up `Solve` in the online documentation and you'll find it works in a very straight forward manner.

Comment: I want to draw this two functions  :  $$\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x^2-2x} - \frac{x+1}{x}$$ , $$\frac{x-1}{x+2}$$ and find the interception points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
s = NSolve[(x^2 - 2 x + 2)/(x^2 - 2 x) - (x + 1)/x == (x - 1)/(x + 2),
    x, Reals];

x /. s
(*{2.93114}*)

(x^2 - 2 x + 2)/(x^2 - 2 x) - (x + 1)/x /. s
(*{0.391622}*)

Show[Plot[{(x^2 - 2 x + 2)/(x^2 - 2 x) - (x + 1)/x, (x - 1)/(
   x + 2)}, {x, -20, 20}], ListPlot[{{x, (x - 1)/(x + 2)} /. s}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot , But when I use your code it shows a failure .

Comment: @S.H.W ?!? It works on my computer. I also re-copied and pasted the above solution and it wors. What errors do you have?

Comment: If you can , send me the file.

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
p1 = Plot[{(x^2 - 2 x + 2)/(x^2 - 2 x) - (x + 1)/x, (x - 1)/(
   x + 2)}, {x, 0, 10}]
sol = Solve[(x^2 - 2 x + 2)/(x^2 - 2 x) - (x + 1)/x == ( x - 1)/(
   x + 2), x]
c = Graphics[{Red, 
    Disk[{N[sol[[3, 1, 2]]], 
      N[(x - 1)/(x + 2) /. x -> sol[[3, 1, 2]] ]}, .05]}];
l = Line[ {{0, 
     N[(x - 1)/(x + 2) /. x -> sol[[3, 1, 2]] ]}, {N[sol[[3, 1, 2]]], 
     N[(x - 1)/(x + 2) /. x -> sol[[3, 1, 2]] ]}, {N[sol[[3, 1, 2]]], 
     0}}];
ll = Graphics[{Dashed, l}];
t = Graphics[Text[N[sol[[3, 1, 2]]], {N[sol[[3, 1, 2]]], -.2}]]
Show[p1, ll, c, t, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```